# If $f:U\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $(x^2+y^4)f(x,y) + (f(x,y))^3=1$, then $f$ is $C^\infty$

Tags: functions, multivariable-calculus, implicit-differentiation

> Let $f:U\to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous in $U \subset\mathbb{R}^2$, such that
>   $$(x^2+y^4)f(x,y) + (f(x,y))^3=1$$
>   for all $(x,y) \in U$. Prove that $f\in C^{\infty}$.

I'm learning the implicit function theorem, I read it, and its proof, and I thought I had understood it. But when I face a problem like this I just don't know how to use it yet. If someone could help me I would appreciate it.

Comment: in wich way do you think the implicit function theorem could help here?

Comment: In fact, I really don't know, I think this problems involves this theorem because it is in the chapter associated with it. So I would like to use it to get practice. But if you can solve without using it, its fine.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider $F\colon \mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R$, $F(x,y,z)=(x^2+y^4)z+z^3$. On the level set $F(x,y,z)=1$, when can you solve for $z$ locally as a (smooth) function of $(x,y)$?

Comment: So, z is a function of $(x,y)$ when $\displaystyle\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}\not= 0$. But $\displaystyle\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}=x^2+y^4 +3z^2=0 \iff (x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$, and $F(0,0,0)=0$. So $1$ is a regular value of F (where $F^{-1}(1)$ has no critical points) and $F^{-1}(1)$ is a function $z=f(x,y)$, since $F\in C^{\infty}$, $f(x,y)\in c^{\infty}$

Comment: I think is that, thanks for the Hint Ted Shifrin!

Comment: Excellent. Provided you actually know the $C^\infty$ version of the implicit function theorem, which is sounds like you do. :) But be careful: The theorem only gives you a *local* statement for $z$ as a function of $(x,y)$. You need to use the hypothesis in your problem that $f$ is continuous on $U$.